# Jasmine test if method call another method only if the inner method is instance of Function

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need to test that code using jasmine@2.99.1

that code from my-component.ts

```
startChatting(agent, platform) {
  if (this.params.startChatting instanceof Function) {
    this.params.startChatting(agent, platform, this.params.rowIndex);
  }
}
```

and that my try to test above code: my-component.spec.ts

```
it('ensure that startChatting does not call "params.startChatting" if "params.startChatting" 
   is not instanceOf Function', () => {
     component.params = {
       startChatting: null,
       rowIndex: 2
     }

     spyOn(component.params, 'startChatting');
     component.startChatting('dummyId', 'telegram');

     expect(component.params.startChatting).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

but the test fails with this message "Error: Expected spy startChatting not to have been called." which mean the inner method is called.

So I try to console log the inner method this I set to null as you see at the beginning of my test case, but I found it not null instead it is as following:

```
ƒ () { return fn.apply(this, arguments); }
```

and I knew that changed after the spyOn function was called.

So my question is how to test such case? and I need to insure that if params.startChatting was not instance of Function, not called.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot test this case. The error is due to null not of type `Jasmine.spy`... You could test via getter on the startChatting parameter

Comment: thanks @Akxe for your replay could you explane how to test via getter or give me link thaat explain that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is not solvable, as you do not have the function to be tested. This might however work for you...

```
let startChattingGetterInwoked = 0;
component.params = {
  get startChatting() {
    startChattingGetterInwoked++;
    return null;
  },
  rowIndex: 2
}

component.startChatting('dummyId', 'telegram');
expect(startChattingGetterInwoked).toBe(1);
// Not sure how offten it is called, but at least one should be called due to `typeof`
```